# Getting the error Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-batch

I am trying to run a basic `SpringBatch` application . I have the  `job` config like below

```
 @Bean
    public Step myStep(@Value("1") int chunkSize,
                                   ItemReader<Input> myReader,
                                   ItemProcessor<Input, Output> myProcessor,
                                   ItemWriter<Output> myWriter,
                                   SkipPolicy mySkipPolicy,
                                   JobRepository jobRepository,
                                   StepExecutionListener myListener) {

        return new StepBuilder("myStep", jobRepository).<Input, Output>chunk(chunkSize)
            .reader(myReader).processor(myProcessor)
            .writer(myWriter).faultTolerant()
            .skipPolicy(mySkipPolicy)
            .listener(myListener)
            .build();
    }
```

I am using in memory `h2db` as the data source . Here is my data source configuration

```
 @Bean(name = "userDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.user.datasource)
    public DataSource userDataSource() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }

    @Bean(name = "batchDataSource")
    @ConfigurationProperties("spring.batch.datasource")
    @Primary
    public DataSource batchDataSource() {

        return DataSourceBuilder.create().build();
    }
```

Here is my  `yaml` config

```
spring:
  application:
    name: my-application
  batch:
    datasource:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
      max-lifetime: ${BATCH_DATASOURCE_MAX_LIFETIME:30000}
      password: sa
      username: sa
  user:
    datasource:
      jdbcUrl: jdbc:h2:mem:db;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1
      max-lifetime: ${USER_DATASOURCE_MAX_LIFETIME:30000}
      password: sa
      username: sa
```

Whenever I am trying to run test cases , I am getting below error

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'jobRepository': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'dataSource' while setting bean property 'dataSource'
```

My class which contains `main` method is in package `example.application` and all the configuration classes I have mentioned above are in package `example.application.config`. I dont think it is a component scan issue. Where am I going wrong? Please let me know if any further details are required.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you are using Spring Batch 5.x, I believe the `jobRepository` bean is looking for a bean named "dataSource." Simply rename your second bean from `@Bean(name = "batchDataSource")` to `@Bean(name = "dataSource")`.